# DDD how to design basket service

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices

I have 2 option.

1)when addItemTobasket request come. gRPC request to product, pricing, user service and get informations . and save them to cart db.

Or not fetch other service information. Save only references like id. And save basket db. When get basket request call gRPC request aggragate all service datas as viewmodel and return that.

2) create shared redis session server and when addeditem to cart event raise itemAddedToCart includes reference ids. And main services consume that event. Product service get product with id that come with event and write Product info shared redis. pricing service price etc. When getbasket request come data is ready in redis.

For 1) it coupled all servies. it is not good for ddd.

For 2) it is async. When user add item to cart. Waits a responsr success or failed.

If there is better best practice please share with Me.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I'd say just go with option 1. It's not as complex as there aren't so many interconnected parts. Also depending on the size of your app, that kind of coupling is easy to remove later on when you gain a better understanding of what is going on.

Comment: It is simple but I want to make best. It is my hobby project.  does it make  bottleneck in heavy loads? When product service down. Basket is useless. Or pricing, shipment.. I dont want that

Comment: Well, then you kind of answered your own question didn't you? If those are the things you want to avoid, you have to make your decisions accordingly.

Comment: yes but second scenerio is async. Actually I need to find new way. Thats why I write this question. I need 3th option.